# "TypeError: 'Klein' object is not callable" while calling an endpoint from AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, zappa

I'm trying to run a simple server

```
from klein import Klein

app = Klein()

@app.route("/")
def hello(request):
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run("localhost", 8080)
```

I packaged and uploaded it to AWS Lambda using Zappa, hover i'm getting this after calling the endpoint, any idea why?

```
"{'message': 'An uncaught exception happened while servicing this request. You can investigate this with the `zappa tail` command.', 'traceback': ['Traceback (most recent call last):\\n', '  File \"/var/task/handler.py\", line 452, in handler\\n    response = Response.from_app(self.wsgi_app, environ)\\n', '  File \"/var/task/werkzeug/wrappers.py\", line 939, in from_app\\n    return cls(*_run_wsgi_app(app, environ, buffered))\\n', '  File \"/var/task/werkzeug/test.py\", line 923, in run_wsgi_app\\n    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)\\n', '  File \"/var/task/zappa/middleware.py\", line 70, in __call__\\n    response = self.application(environ, encode_response)\\n', \"TypeError: 'Klein' object is not callable\\n\"]}"
```

Comment: Does your virtual environment have Klein installed?

Comment: take a look in the logs using `zappa tail` as mentioned in your message.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot call the object **Klein()**. You need to add it to the virtualenv in order to import it as only the virtualenv is build and deployed with zappa.

For example, you could create a setup.py script which allows to install your custom code with pip to your virtual environment as described here: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html